# Error opening ffmpeg subprocess in Python

Tags: python, ffmpeg, subprocess

What I want to do is opening a ffmpeg process in Python. My code look like this:

```
import subprocess
import os

def Main():
    ffmpeg = "C:\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe"
    args = " -i C:\video.mp4 -r 1 -f image2 C:\FRAMES\frame-%03d.jpg"
    subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg + args).wait()

Main()
```

But even in this simple form I got always the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Francesco/Desktop/test.py", line 9, in <module>
    Main()
  File "C:/Users/Francesco/Desktop/test.py", line 7, in Main
    subprocess.Popen(ffmpeg + args).wait()
  File "C:\Users\Francesco\Desktop\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.4\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)
  File "C:\Users\Francesco\Desktop\WinPython-64bit-2.7.9.4\python-2.7.9.amd64\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)
WindowsError: [Error 2] Impossibile trovare il file specificato
>>>
```

What's wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to escape out the backslash and also give a space between the two

```
ffmpeg = "C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe "
args = " -i C:\\video.mp4 -r 1 -f image2 C:\\FRAMES\\frame-%03d.jpg"
```

However, this is not the recommended way.
You should have a list which you pass as args rather than a string.

```
cmd = ['C:\\ffmpeg\\bin\\ffmpeg.exe', '-i', 'C:\\video.mp4', '-r', '1', '-f', 'C:\\FRAMES\\frame-%03d.jpg']
```

Comment: Thank you with this the code seems working. But I can't explain why in other parts of the code I used the single "\" in path to, for example, read a file or define a destination path, and it works

Comment: `\b` translates to `'\x08'`, but `\ ` translates to `\\ `. So depends on what path you had put in. Its always safer to use `\\\`